# Creating dataframe in R with multiple lines of the same hour

Tags: r, list, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to create a dataframe with the following columns: dt, depth, var1

But I need 4 lines of each hour going through a whole year as I need to adjust var1 at certain depths:

| dt | depth | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008-01-01 00:00 | 2 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 00:00 | 40 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 00:00 | 45 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 00:00 | 100 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 01:00 | 2 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 01:00 | 40 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 01:00 | 45 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 01:00 | 100 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 02:00 | 2 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 02:00 | 40 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 02:00 | 45 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 02:00 | 100 | 0.01 |
| 2008-01-01 03:00 | 2 | 0.01 |

How do I create the "dt" list for the first column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
start_date_time <- as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 00:00", format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end_date_time <- as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 03:00", format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

df <- data.frame(dt = rep(seq(start_date_time, end_date_time, by = 3600), each = 4), 
                 depth = rep(c(2, 40, 45, 100)),
                 var1 = 0.01)

df
#>                     dt depth var1
#> 1  2008-01-01 00:00:00     2 0.01
#> 2  2008-01-01 00:00:00    40 0.01
#> 3  2008-01-01 00:00:00    45 0.01
#> 4  2008-01-01 00:00:00   100 0.01
#> 5  2008-01-01 01:00:00     2 0.01
#> 6  2008-01-01 01:00:00    40 0.01
#> 7  2008-01-01 01:00:00    45 0.01
#> 8  2008-01-01 01:00:00   100 0.01
#> 9  2008-01-01 02:00:00     2 0.01
#> 10 2008-01-01 02:00:00    40 0.01
#> 11 2008-01-01 02:00:00    45 0.01
#> 12 2008-01-01 02:00:00   100 0.01
#> 13 2008-01-01 03:00:00     2 0.01
#> 14 2008-01-01 03:00:00    40 0.01
#> 15 2008-01-01 03:00:00    45 0.01
#> 16 2008-01-01 03:00:00   100 0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great, just one thing, if you can paste your data into the question using `dput(your_data)` or as a data frame object (as in the answer) this makes your question reproducible and easier to test. Your question is based on relatively simple dataset but future questions  might not be. See [MRE] for handy hints.

Comment: Thank you. Still new to this forum but I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid` :

```
expand.grid(
  dt = seq(as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 00:00:00", 'UTC'), 
           as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 03:00:00", 'UTC'), 'hour'), 
  depth = c(2, 40, 45, 100), 
  var1 = 0.01
) -> result

result

#                    dt depth var1
#1  2008-01-01 00:00:00     2 0.01
#2  2008-01-01 01:00:00     2 0.01
#3  2008-01-01 02:00:00     2 0.01
#4  2008-01-01 03:00:00     2 0.01
#5  2008-01-01 00:00:00    40 0.01
#6  2008-01-01 01:00:00    40 0.01
#7  2008-01-01 02:00:00    40 0.01
#8  2008-01-01 03:00:00    40 0.01
#9  2008-01-01 00:00:00    45 0.01
#10 2008-01-01 01:00:00    45 0.01
#11 2008-01-01 02:00:00    45 0.01
#12 2008-01-01 03:00:00    45 0.01
#13 2008-01-01 00:00:00   100 0.01
#14 2008-01-01 01:00:00   100 0.01
#15 2008-01-01 02:00:00   100 0.01
#16 2008-01-01 03:00:00   100 0.01
```

If you want order as shown you can arrange the above result or use `tidyr::expand_grid` :

```
tidyr::expand_grid(
  dt = seq(as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 00:00:00", 'UTC'), 
           as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 03:00:00", 'UTC'), 'hour'), 
  depth = c(2, 40, 45, 100), 
  var1 = 0.01
) -> result

result

# A tibble: 16 x 3
#   dt                  depth  var1
#   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2008-01-01 00:00:00     2  0.01
# 2 2008-01-01 00:00:00    40  0.01
# 3 2008-01-01 00:00:00    45  0.01
# 4 2008-01-01 00:00:00   100  0.01
# 5 2008-01-01 01:00:00     2  0.01
# 6 2008-01-01 01:00:00    40  0.01
# 7 2008-01-01 01:00:00    45  0.01
# 8 2008-01-01 01:00:00   100  0.01
# 9 2008-01-01 02:00:00     2  0.01
#10 2008-01-01 02:00:00    40  0.01
#11 2008-01-01 02:00:00    45  0.01
#12 2008-01-01 02:00:00   100  0.01
#13 2008-01-01 03:00:00     2  0.01
#14 2008-01-01 03:00:00    40  0.01
#15 2008-01-01 03:00:00    45  0.01
#16 2008-01-01 03:00:00   100  0.01
```